# Does it make sense to think of a non-constant solution to $\frac{dx}{dt}=0$ (A steady state solution)?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

For instance if $\displaystyle\frac{dx}{dt}=x-t$, then $\displaystyle\frac{dx}{dt}=0$ at $x=t$

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Are there systems where $\displaystyle\frac{dx}{dt}=0$ but $x$ is non-constant?

Comment: Looking at the title, even sympathetically, what does "non-constant" mean with respect to a "steady state solution"?  Having a derivative zero at one argument does not mean being constant.  Talk of a "steady state solution" should be defined presumably for all times.

Comment: @usainlightning yes!, consider $f(x) = \left \lceil{x}\right \rceil $ (this is the function that outputs $x$ rounded up.

Comment: @frogeyedpeas Sorry I meant $\displaystyle\frac{dx}{dt} \equiv 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really make sense here to say "at $x=t$" because if $x$ always equals $t$, then the equation just says $\frac{dx}{dx}=x-x$, or $1=0$, which doesn't make sense.

The short answer to your question is no. Given the differential equation $\frac{dx}{dt}=0$, we know that the only possible solution is a constant.

There is a rigorous answer which gives us the *existence* of a certain set of solutions (any constant), and *uniqueness* of those solutions (there are no others). [This page](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~tyson/existence.pdf) has a rigorous proof of those theorems if you are interested.